# Substring from the beginning of a word

Tags: c#, substring

The HTTP GET response for a request is like below

```
    <html>
      <head>        <script type="text/javascript">----</script>        <script type="text/javascript">---</script>             <title>Detailed Notes</title>
      </head>
      <body style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-width: 0px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13; color: #000000">           <p>this is one note&nbsp;</p>  </body>      </html>
```

I am getting this as a string and i have to read the body part out of it.

I tried HtmlAgility pack, but HTML parsing is getting failed due to some specials in the html content (I think something from the commented script causing this issue).

So to read the  tag content i am thinking of a SubString operation.

Like SubString from the beginning of `<body tag`.

How can we do SubString from the beginning of a word from a text?

Comment: So, are you going to edit your question to include a question? Please read [ask].

Comment: you want only content of Body? or like should we include "<body" and 
 "/body>" too ? have you thought about Regex ?

Comment: just  body content .Yes Regx  is useful i guess. But CSS styles of body tag might cause some troubles i guess

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple `SubString()` with `IndexOf`() + `LastIndexOf()`:

```
string BodyContent = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf("</body>") - 1).Substring(input.IndexOf("<body"));
BodyContent = BodyContent.Substring(BodyContent.IndexOf(">") + 1).Trim();
```

This will return:
 
`<p> this is one note&nbsp;</p>`

```
string FullBody = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf("</body>") + 7).Substring(input.IndexOf("<body")).Trim();
```

This will return:

`<body style = background-color: #FFFFFF; border-width: 0px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13; color: #000000' >< p > this is one note&nbsp;</p>  </body>`

Answer (score 1):

The " will cause a problme so you need to replace every " after you get the request source

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(); // make an instance of webclient
string source = client.DownloadString("url").Replace("\"",",,"); // get the html source and escape " with any charachter
string code = "<body style=\"background-color: #FFFFFF; border-width: 0px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13; color: #000000\">           <p>this is one note&nbsp;</p>  </body>";
MatchCollection m0 = Regex.Matches(code, "(<body)(?<body>.*?)(</body>)", RegexOptions.Singleline); // use RE to get between tags
foreach (Match m in m0) // loop through the results
{
    string result = m.Groups["body"].Value.Replace(",,", "\""); // get the result and replace the " back
}
```

Comment: the inline css  of BODY tag varies from response to response